# Discord.py Extract user from reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am writing a feature in my bot which allows 2 users to duel each other, and the way it works is that the bot sends a message telling everyone to get ready and then after a random number of seconds pass the bot reactions with a certain emoji on the message and the first person in the duel reacts to the message wins. It a simple I idea but I can't figure out how to see if a certain user has reacted to the message. My question is - is this possible or do I have to figure out another approach to this?

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely possible with `wait_for` which is documented [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Client.wait_for).
The `wait_for` function waits for any specified event listed in the [event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord-api-events).

It takes in three parameters `Event`, `Check (optional)` and `timeout(optional)`

there are examples in the documentation but for you it would be something like:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', case_insensitive=True)

@bot.command()
async def game(ctx):
    # Whatever you want here
    msg = await ctx.send("React first to win")
    await msg.add_reaction('')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return str(reaction.emoji) == '' and user != bot.user

    try:
        # Timeout parameter is optional but sometimes can be useful
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30, check=check)
        
        # Will wait until a user reacts with the specified checks then continue on with the code
        await ctx.send(f"Congratulations {user.name} you won!")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:

        # when wait_for reaches specified timeout duration (in this example it is 30 seconds)
        await ctx.send("You ran out of time!")
```

The `Timeout=30` parameter is 100% optional you can remove it so it would wait forever (or until you turn your bot off). The `check` parameter is also optional.

P.S. I am assuming you are using python 3 or more hence the F-strings

Comment: Hey quick question, how would I write this in a cog, because I am having some trouble converting this

Comment: you would add a self parameter to the function which turns into `async def game(self, ctx):` and every `bot` instance in this code would be turned into `self.bot`

for example `self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30, check=check)`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's possible for sure, there are multiple ways for doing this, I never tried it before since I didn't create any bots with reaction things but that should work.

using [on_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add)

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = client.get_channel('123')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != channel.id:
        return
    else:
        if reaction.emoji == "✅":
            #Do something
            print(user.name)
            print(user.discriminator)
            await channel.send(f"{user} has won the game")
```

Make sure to take a look at the on_reaction_add documentation and the [reaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction) one